# Access: how to set default value on bound combo box using property sheet

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba, default-value

Using Access 2010, I have a payment terms combobox (bound to Invoice.TermsID) on an invoice form with row source set to a simple query with a list of payment terms (3 cols: id, description, value).  Stored in the BillTo table, I have the default payment terms (Billto.TermsID) for each customer.

When a new invoice is started, I want the default payment terms to show in the combobox just like the textbox (bound to invoice.invoicedate) shows the default value =Now()), and then it can be changed when necessary.

I tried using DLookUp("[TermsID]","[BillTo]","BilltoID=" & [Invoice.BillToID]) as Default Value in the Property Sheet but it doesn't work.  The Dlookup works as I validated it in vba.

I don't think I can use Form.OnCurrent() event because when you move from invoice to invoice it will change the terms from the chosen terms, and when anything changes, my code invokes an popup that asks if you want to save changes.

I just want it to work like the invoice.invoicedate textbox and the default value.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a combobox for selecting BillToID? Maybe use its AfterUpdate event. I think `[ ]` around [Invoice.BillToID] are incorrect. Use just `[BillToID]`.

Comment: Ya, I put the code in the AfterUpdate of the first field on the invoice.  But, my question was why doesn't the defaultvalue work on the property sheet for the combobox.  That's where it should go.  this is just a workaround imho.

Comment: When is BillToID input? I suspect the criteria is simply not available to New Record. Note that DefaultValue data displays on NewRecord row even before data is input. It will not recalculate when data is input, therefore it will not work with your conditional DLookup.

Comment: BilltoID is set prior when an order is entered into Order table which is linked to Invoice table.  Once the billing rate is entered, it creates a record the Invoice table.  This is when the default value=Now() for the invoicedate field is shown. So I expected the Dlookup for the terms combobox to behave in same manner.

Comment: You see the Now() DefaultValue is calculated on the New Record row and displays even before record is initiated. Your conditional expression cannot do this. OrderNum is not in the Invoice record until after the record is initiated with some other input, so is not available to the DefaultValue to calculate with. A DefaultValue must be able to calculate before record is initiated which is what Now() and Date() can do.